# PuTTY : run knit when putty logs in

Tags: linux, ssh

When I log onto remote linux host with putty ssh, it asks me to run "knit -f"  (once a day)
if I don't run that command it starts asking me for password for all the git commands "git pull"

I want to know why does this happen, and if there is a way to automatically run this command every time my putty session starts.

Comment: Please note that this has nothing to do with PuTTY.  PuTTY is just a terminal emulator, and your question is about using Linux and the shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the command to the startup file of your shell on the linux host (e.g. `.bash_profile` if you use `bash`.)